# How to install Collabnet SubVersion?

Tags: delphi, svn, delphi-xe

There is any documentation on how to install and setup and SubVersion server? And use it with Delphi XE over a network.

To say otherwise: I have installed Delphi XE, Subversion Client and Server. Now what? I don't understand how they work.

Comment: This doesn't seem like a programming question.

Comment: Hi Sorpigal. This question is about Delphi and SVN. Per total, these two categories have more than 10000 entries. Please check the facts if you don't believe.

Comment: I suggest reading the [documentation](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/index.en.html)

Comment: Hi Uwe. I already have that so called manual. It was delivered on Delphi XE CD. But is says nothing about how to install and setup the Windows edition of SubVersion. I guess they removed those chapters because they want to make money with their online support - they have really big fees.

Comment: Big fees are an often encountered gimmick with free software.

Comment: @Sorpigal: It's on topic for three reasons. 1&2) Delphi is both a programming language and an IDE; 3) SVN is a commonly used programmer's tool. All three of those are on topic here; see the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) for details.

Comment: This should be migrated to **serverfault** and/or **superuser** if OP doesnt want to build or port it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest installing VisualSVN Server, which is a complete installation of the latest Subversion server plus Apache, with a nice control panel to configure stuff.  It integrates with Windows authentication, or you can have it use Subversion authentication.  It's fantastic.
http://www.visualsvn.com/server/

Comment: Thanks Chris. I will take a look because this CollabNet package is a nightmare. So, I install Visual SVN as server and Colabnet Client as client?

Comment: I use TortoiseSVN as the client.

Comment: if you need command-line client, SlikSVN (http://www.sliksvn.com/en/download) is pretty good and easy to install

Comment: He's already got a command-line client, as he said he installed the subversion client (which is command-line).  I recommend that he look into Tortoise.

Comment: Actually I don't want a command line tool. I want a modern tool with GUI.

Answer (score 0):

- You only need to install a Subversion server if you need networked access to the repository. If you only need local access, you can use a local repository. You can [create it using a subversion client](http://vincenthomedev.wordpress.com/2007/10/15/setup-svn-local-repository-step-by-step/), like [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/), and it is accessed using the `file:///` protocol.
- Delphi XE has [an integrated SVN client](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/How_To_Use_Subversion_in_the_IDE), so it's not mandatory to install an external Subversion client, though it's really helpful as are many tasks that can't be made with the integrated client. TortoiseSVN is superb and integrates seamlessly with Windows explorer.

Comment: So, if I have Subversion installed, Delphi will detect it and connect automatically to it? If not, there is a manual that explains how to setup Delphi to work together with Subversion?

Comment: You need to manually enter the address of the repository. Take a look at [Adding a Project to Version Control](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Adding_a_Project_to_Version_Control) and [Delphi XE and Subversion Integration](http://www.drbob42.com/examines/examinD3.htm).

Answer (score 0):

> Thanks Chris. I will take a look because this CollabNet package is a nightmare. So, I install Visual SVN as server and Colabnet Client as client?

You can use almost any subversion client with almost any subversion server. Subversion has a well defined API that both clients and servers can follow. The only problem is that some clients are incompatible with each other. For example, VisualStudio's AnkhSVN client can create `_svn` directories instead of `.svn` which can make it incompatible with the standard command line client.

If you don't mind using `svnserve` as the server, you can download the [SlikSVN](http://www.sliksvn.com/en/download/). The `svnserve` server is fairly straight forward and quick to setup and install. It isn't as flexible as the Apache server (which can have more than one repository served under the same httpd instant) but it's nice to use for your own personal self or for a small group.

I looked at the licensing of VisualSVN, and it looks like its zero cost as long as you don't need the advanced features.

Comment: What I don't understand is this: has Delphi XE a subversioning system included or not. In the feature matrix they pretend they have. But I can't find it. It seems that the Subversion kit they provide on the CD is the so called 'integrated feature'. I don't mint if this feature is not integrated in Delphi and it comes as an external tool. The question is: does it work? If yes, how to make it work? Where is the documentation?

Comment: @Altar - There are two parts to Subversion: The client and the server. Delphi XE probably has a Subversion client built into it. It's very common for IDEs like Delphi XE to do this. However, your client has to connect to a Subversion repository which is done by talking through the Subversion server. That's what svnserve and VisualSVN are. They are servers that run the Subversion source repository.